# Adding watermark to PDF using iText7 C#

Tags: c#, watermark, itext7

I am using iText 7 for C#, or actually I am migrating from iTextSharp 5 to iText 7. In iTextSharp, I have used `IPdfPageEvent` (more specifically the `PdfPageEventHelper` helper class) to add a watermark to PDF:

```
public MyPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
  private Image waterMark;
  public MyPageEvent(Image img) {
    waterMark = img;
  }
  public void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc) {
    PdfContentByte content = writer.GetUnderContent();
    content.AddImage(waterMark);
  }
}

Image watermarkImage = new Image(imgPath);
watermarkImage.setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
writer.setPageEvent( new MyPageEvent(watermarkImage) );
```

Now that i am looking for iText 7 equivalent for that. I can't find the `IPageEvent` interface, nor classes such as `PdfPageEventHelper` in iText 7 for C#.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [Chapter 7: Handling events; setting viewer preferences and writer properties](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-writer-properties) where the event system is explained.

In this chapter, we explain how to use the `addEventHandler()` method for the following events:

- `START_PAGE`– triggered when a new page is started,
- `END_PAGE`– triggered right before a new page is started,
- `INSERT_PAGE`– triggered when a page is inserted, and
- `REMOVE_PAGE`– triggered when a page is removed.

In iText 5, it was necessary to add a watermark in the `OnEndPage()` method. In iText 7, you can choose for the `START_PAGE` or `END_PAGE` event.

Suppose that you want to add an image as a watermark. In that case, you'd create an implementation of the `IEventHandler` interface like this:

```
protected class TransparentImage implements IEventHandler {
    protected PdfExtGState gState;
    protected Image img;
    public TransparentImage(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        gState = new PdfExtGState().setFillOpacity(0.2f);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
            page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
        pdfCanvas.saveState().setExtGState(gState);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, page.getPageSize());
        canvas.add(img
            .scaleAbsolute(pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight()));
        pdfCanvas.restoreState();
        pdfCanvas.release();
    }
}
```

There's also an example where we add text instead of an image. More specifically the a header:

```
protected class Header implements IEventHandler {
    String header;
    public Header(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        if (pdf.getPageNumber(page) == 1) return;
        Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(
            page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
        canvas.showTextAligned(header,
            pageSize.getWidth() / 2,
            pageSize.getTop() - 30, TextAlignment.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Using such an `IEventHandler` implementation is easy:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE,
    new Header("The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde"));
```

As you can see, you can simply add the event handler to the `PdfDocument` specifying for which event the handler has to be triggered.

**Important:** the code I shared is Java code, but the same classes, interfaces and methods exist in C#, so it shouldn't be a problem for you to adapt my examples.